# How do I get my specific menu to make the active element have a different color

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I know that this question has been answered before, but I can't figure out how to do it with my code because of the amount of div's and the amount of classes. How can I make the active page have a different background color. I'm using a responsive twitter bootstrap (2) frame so you have to stretch the viewing window out to see all the tabs at the top.

The jsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/2bhnQ/1/

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" href="#">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="index.php">HOME</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="people.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">People<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="people.php">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#staff">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#grad">Graduate Students</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#undergrad">Undergraduate Students</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#visitors">Visitors and Affiliates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#interns">Interns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="people.php#alumni">InfoLab Alumni</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="publications.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="publications.php">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="publications.php#start-and-omnibase">START and Omnibase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="publications.php#question-answering">Question Answering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="publications.php#semantic">The Semantic Web</a></li>
                        <li><a href="publications.php#other">Other Publications</a></li></ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="start-system.php">How START works</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried doing something like this, but it didn't work. (This is just an answer from another stackoverflow, so I guessed it would be helpful, but I can use $(location).attr('href') or any other option if it helps.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(window.location.pathname);
$(".navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top .navbar-inner .container .nav-collapse .nav li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href")==window.location.pathname)
        $(this).addClass("active");
}) })
```

As a novice programmer in my first month on the job, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend doing it on the server side

Comment: If what you want to do is make the background of the active link a different color so the user knows what page he/she is on, have you considered using the css `a:active` selector as a solution?

Comment: @Nick Where would I put it in my code? Would I have to do something crazy like '.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top .navbar-inner .container .nav-collapse .nav li a:active {color:red}' or could I simply add 'a:active {color:red}'

Comment: @Prisoner What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.navbar-inverse` nested within a `.navbar`, so your selector isn't finding anything.

Its hard for me to test without your full set up, but try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(window.location.pathname);
$(".navbar .navbar-inner .container .nav-collapse .nav li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href")==window.location.pathname)
        $(this).addClass("active");
}) })
```

Comment: I'll add a jsFiddle in a moment. What you suggested didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: Try using `window.location.href` or `$(location).attr('href')` instead of window.location.pathname.

Comment: I would step through the loop with firebug and make sure it is doing what you expect. Something is going wrong.

Comment: I just downloaded firebug. What should I look for?

Comment: open the script tab, refresh the page, set a breakpoint on your document.ready function, and start going through each step. Make sure it is looping through correctly and the variables have the values you expect.

Comment: Is this what I'm looking through? If so, for what? "
/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),function(e,n){t[n]=!0}),t}function H(e,n,r){if(r===t&&e.nodeType===1){var i="data-"+n.replace(P,"-$1").toLowerCase();r=e.getAttribute(i);if(typeof r=="string"){try{r=r==="true"?!0:r==="false"?!1:r==="null"?null:+r+""===r?+r:D.t...
"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34652/discussion-between-nick-and-alex)

Answer (score 1):

$(".navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top .navbar-inner .container .nav-collapse .nav li a")
this isn't going to target what you're looking for.  If you want to be as specific as you're being you need:
$(".navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top .navbar-inner .container .nav-collapse .nav li a")

The spaces in the selector imply hierarchy, if you want one element with multiple classes, you leave no space between the classes. .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top is the div with all 3 classes.

Most likely, you'd be safe targeting just .navbar instead of .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top

Comment: I tried both suggestions and neither one worked. Thanks though. I am trying to target the three main pages of "people" "publications" and "How START works".

Comment: I would add a class to those so you can target them specifically.  Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/QT2AR/
Also, if you want to use window.location.pathname for your compare, you're going to have to strip the '/' off of it first.  There are some general purpose functions out there that do just that (look at the 1st comment on this page  http://befused.com/javascript/get-filename-url)

Comment: What was the difference between your jsfiddle and mine? I couldn't see any difference. Also, I'm not stuck on using window.location.pathname. That was just the solution that someone found on another stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: What didn't work?  The background of the People menu isn't pink?

Comment: I didn't notice the pink before because I didn't click ok on all the boxes, but doing that just made people pink no matter what page you are on and only after the 6 alerts came up. It is a start, but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Well, the page name on jsfiddle is never going to match your pages, so I chose one to highlight.  The alerts were added to show you what you are comparing against (so you can see that you need to remove the / in the value returned by window.location.pathname.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with jquery, try using href selector. It goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href="publications.php#start-and-omnibase"]').css('background','red');
});
```

You can always add some selectors before 'a' tag so it only goes for specific element or area.For example:

`$('#menu a[href="publications.php#start-and-omnibase"]').css('background','red');`

Should work like charm, only what you need to do is set this href path dynamic.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
```

Of course you need to parse this url variable to correct value.
Hope it helps :)

Also I seen now that you asked what does mean making active item on server side. It means that you add class "active" on item that is currently active while you generating that menu on server side(with PHP or whatever) and sending it to client side with all classes set. If menu is not static, and it's always generated by some server side language depending on menu items which are gathered from DB or any other way, while you generate menu items you can also check if current location of user is same as current menu item href, and if it is you can easily set class of this item to active.

Comment: That all sounds good, but I don't really know what you are talking about. Thanks though.

Comment: Just add this line:
$('a[href="publications.php#start-and-omnibase"]').css('background','red');
To your document ready event listner, which is:
$(document).ready(function(){
-->here goes line of code
});
After you do that you will see what is red and you'll get it all :)